# How can I convert/migrate root f/s to LVM 2 Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 14.04

I am experiencing space issue on root file system and I am decided to migrate current f/s to lvm2. Can any one tell how do I proceed it to further........

Answer (score -1):

You might check out [Blocks](https://github.com/g2p/blocks#readme) but be sure to have a complete backup of your data on a separate hard drive before using it and also make sure to check the [issues](https://github.com/g2p/blocks/issues) of this tool as development has stopped three years ago.